# Change Style from code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this style

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontSize" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="False">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property= "FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Now, if I want to change the **Setter Property Value** from code behind how can I do it ?

In code behind I'd want something like this:

```
MainMenuStyle.IsMouseOver(True).Foreground = "Red"
MainMenuStyle.IsMouseOver(True).FontSize = 10

MainMenuStyle.IsMouseOver(False).Foreground = "Green"
MainMenuStyle.IsMouseOver(False).FontSize = 100
```

I must use only framework 4.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giangregorio has covered most of the reason why this can't be achieved *directly*. However, here's a solution:

You can use `DynamicResource` references in your style's `Setters`, then when you need to change the style, you **simply update the resource**, instead of the style. This would probably make more sense with an example:

```
<!-- Colour Resources -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueBrush" Color="Blue"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedBrush" Color="Red"/>

<!-- TextBlock Style (References the colour resources) -->
<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> 

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BlueBrush}"/>
            ...
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="False">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource RedBrush}" />
            ...
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

So. As the `Foreground` properties reference a `DynamicResource`, whenever the resource changes, it'll update the `Style`. All you need to do in code is change the resource value.

```
App.Current.Resources["BlueBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
```

The `DynamicResource` will take care of the rest.

Comment: I was just sitting there thinking I knew wpf supported style binding stuff. +1

Comment: Good idea ;-) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change your style after its first use, from MSDN:

> A style is sealed when another style is based on it or when it is
>   applied for the first time.

In your case i will probably define another style in XAML and switch them at runtime.

Otherwise if you hadn't used it yet, you can do something like this (using index to make a fast example)

```
  Style style = this.Resources["MainMenuStyle"] as Style;
  ((Trigger)style.Triggers[0]).Setters[0] = new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
  yourControl.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code.

```
<!-- Colour Resources -->
<!-- Default values -->

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem_Select_Color" Color="Blue"/>
<FontFamily x:Key="MenuItem_Select_Font">Calibri</FontFamily>
<sys:Double x:Key="MenuItem_Select_Font_Size">13</sys:Double>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem_UnSelect_Color" Color="Green"/>
<FontFamily x:Key="MenuItem_UnSelect_Font">Arial Black</FontFamily>
<sys:Double x:Key="MenuItem_UnSelect_Font_Size">12</sys:Double>



<!-- TextBlock Style (References the colour resources) -->
<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_Select_Color}"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_Select_Font}"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_Select_Font_Size}"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="False">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_UnSelect_Color}"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_UnSelect_Font}"/>
            <Setter Property= "FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MenuItem_UnSelect_Font_Size}"/>                
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Code behind

```
        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_Select_Color") = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkBlue)
        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_UnSelect_Color") = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold)

        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_Select_Font") = New FontFamily("Broadway")
        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_UnSelect_Font") = New FontFamily("Lucida Console")

        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_Select_Font_Size") = 20
        Application.Current.Resources("MenuItem_UnSelect_Font_Size") = 30
```

Bye